# use of for loop in shell script

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I have written one shell script where trying to run the `gnuplot` .

**run_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script to generate the graph "

date 

shopt -s extglob
rm -rf *.png

gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file0.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file1.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file2.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file3.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file4.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file5.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file6.gpl
gnuplot /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/display_file7.gpl
```

But when I want to replace this gnu plot statements from script and use this `for loop` in script but I am getting path error.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script to generate the graph "

date 

shopt -s extglob
rm -rf *.png

FILES=/path/to//localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/*gpl
for f in $FILES
do
    gnuplot $f
done
```

Error: `"/path/to//localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/*gpl", line 0: Cannot open script file '/path/to//localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/*gpl'`

**NOTE**: These *.gpl files are present in `plot_graph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `/path/to` is doing there; that looks more like pseudocode people write for generic examples. You're question already has the exact path to use:

```
for f in /localtemp/$USER/video_project/build/../plot_graph/*.gpl; do
    gnuplot "$f"
done
```